# Best way to create something like lodash get in typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, lodash

I am trying to find the best way to create a type-safe version of lodash `get()` function.
I did my research and I have come up with a get function that works something like this (The actual types are a bit more complicated):

```
export function get<Target>(getter: () => Target, defaultValue: Target): Target {
    try {
      return getter();
     } catch (e) {
       return defaultValue;
     }
}
```

This works nice, and it allows me to do something like this:

```
get(() => a!.b!.c!.d, 'someDefaultValue');
```

but I really don't like the "!" syntax. It feels unneeded.
I have found some alternative [solutions](https://github.com/RIP21/ts-get) for this, that try to convert the given object into an "all optional" type (Partial), but things get nasty when trying to convert it back to the real object and I don't like it.

Is there a way to get rid of the "!" syntax? 
I even thought of maybe writing a custom rule for typescript that will swallow the "Object is possibly 'undefined'.ts(2532)" error if we are inside the context of my get function, but I don't know if typescript allows this kind of stuff.

Any suggestions?

Edit: for the ones who are interested in the full declaration of the function, I used function overloading to cover all the cases so it looks like this:

```
export function get<Target>(getter: () => Target): Target | undefined;
export function get<Target>(getter: () => Target, defaultValue: Target): Target;
export function get(getter: () => any, defaultValue?: any): any {
  try {
    return getter();
  } catch (e) {
    return defaultValue;
  }
}
```

Comment: `!.` is not type safe.

Comment: look at the implementation of the function. the expression is surrounded with try/catch, so you will not get an exception in case the path does not exist.

Comment: Check optional chaining
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining

Comment: Your getter can fail, but you don't reflect it in the signature. IDK how to reflect it in Typescript; Haskell / Scala / Rust would use `Maybe` or `Option`.

Comment: 9000, this is just a simplified version of the implementation. the real one uses function overloading to catch all the cases.

Comment: With your current function signature, omitting `!` is not possible. You have no control over the object `a` and its type, as you use `get` as a closure. If you really wanted to get rid of `!`, you could hand in the object type with something like `get<Target, T extends object>(getter: (a: DeepRequired<T>) => Target): Target | undefined`, where `DeepRequired` would mark every property of `T` as non-optional for typing purposes. TypeScript 3.7 will have [optional chaining](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16), which semantially is the right choice here.